# I steal the light... what am I?

Tags: riddle

> I take the light
>
> Turn it into my own
>
> Then at day
>
> Turn to stone

What am I?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you

> the moon?

It

> steals the sun's light,

and if you see it in the day it

> just looks more like a stone.

Comment: Yea it is. Also, is this a good riddle?

Comment: A good riddle has a unique answer, and yes, there seems to be one answer here which fits better than anything else. It's quite easy though: some harder riddles involve more different clues which *less clearly* point to a solution, so that it takes more time to figure out what that solution is, but there's still only one that fits everything.

Answer (score 5):

The answer could be

> The moon
> As it take the light of the sun and turns it into its own i.e. it reflects the light of the sun
> And also it is not seen during the day so it can be said that it turns into a stone
> or it is... well... made of stone

Comment: Lies, the moon is made of cheese!

Comment: It is often clearly visible during the day, though it appears more mundane

Answer (score 2):

You could also be:

> One of these:
>  [image: Solar powered lights]

I take the light

> They are solar-powered

Turn it into my own

> They emit light at night from energy collected during the day

Then at day

Turn to stone

> They do not light up during the day, so are as useful as a stone.

Comment: Could be! Didn't think of this before.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer. I was thinking about:

> Tree

I take the light

Turn it into my own

> Trees take the light and feed on it through Photosynthesis. Hence, they convert the light into themselves.

Then at day

Turn to stone

> Don't know.

Comment: For the 'turn to stone' part, maybe you could come up with an explanation having to do with petrification. I'm not sure how you could tie in 'day', though.